# How to get two table's data in one?

Tags: java, mysql, servlets

I have Two Tables in my database one is `Syncbill` and other is `Paymentmode` in `Syncbill`. I have several columns which are representing the payment type for example cash, Paytm and others are `Otherpayment1`,`OtherPayment2` and so on.

I have one more table in my database named as `paymentmode` where otherpayment mode names are defined  like `OtherPayment1` is defined as swiggy there.

Table syncbill

[image: Syncbill]

Table Paymentmode

[image: Paymentmode]

resultant Table/Output

[image: Result]

I am trying to get if it is done by query

Issue I am facing is:

- There is no relation between these two tables
- The relation I have made is in `Paymentmode` table there are four columns named as `Position`,`Paymentcode`,`Paymentname` and `IsActive`  where position is defined as 1,2,3,4 and so on, so these 1,2,3... and in other table `Otherpayment1`,`Otherpayment2`.. here 1,2,3 are defining payment modes
- now what I am trying to do is to get data from both tables but as the place of `Otherpayment1` I want what is in other table (`Paymentmode`) at position 1
- As in table `Paymentmode` I have a column `IsActive` so I want to get only those `PaymentNames` which has `IsActive='Y'`
- I am not getting any idea how can I do that, I am posting this one to get an approach like how can I do that, it can be done with the query itself or I have to use server-side language I am using Java-Servlets as server-side language

What I was doing earlier:

I am writing this query:

```
    SELECT billdate,SUM(paytm) paytm,SUM(cash) cash,
    SUM(otherpayment1) Swiggy, SUM(otherpayment2) KB,SUM(otherpayment3) BigBasket,SUM(otherpayment4) 
    Zomato FROM syncbill WHERE a.BILLDATE BETWEEN '2018-08-05' AND '25018-08-10'
```

and I my Java servlet I am using `resultset.getstring` to get the values from database and then storing them into List and then converting it into JSON using `GSON` like this

```
while (resultSet.next()) {
            lhm = new LinkedHashMap<Object, Object>();
            Billdate = resultSet.getString("billdate");
            cash = resultSet.getLong("paytm");
            creditcard = resultSet.getLong("cash");
            swiggy = resultSet.getLong("Swiggy");
            kb = resultSet.getLong("KB");
            bigBasket = resultSet.getLong("BigBasket");
            zomato = resultSet.getLong("Zomato");

            lhm.put("Billdate", Billdate);          
            lhm.put("Paytm", paytm);
            lhm.put("Cash", cash);
            lhm.put("Swiggy", swiggy);
            lhm.put("Kb", kb);
            lhm.put("BigBasket", bigBasket);
            lhm.put("Zomato", zomato);

            mainList.add(lhm);
            str = gson.toJson(mainList);

        }
```

But this one is not the solution as I am getting KB, Swiggy all of them hard-coded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done by using 2 sql queries

```
//to convert row on Paymentmode table into column name of syncbill table
    String q1 = "select concat('OTHERPAYMENT',p) as op from Paymentmode where IsActive=Y"; 
    rs = stmt.executeQuery(q1); 
    String str = ""; 
    while(rs.next()) {   
    str += rs.getString(1) + ","; 
    }
//to get desired result
    String q2 = "select Paytm, Cash," + str.substring(0, str.length()-1) +" from syncbill";

// below this execute q2
```

Comment: hey sir i didn't get it, can you explain it little bit

Comment: As per the sample table data which you defined above,
String str will have OTHERPAYMENT1,OTHERPAYMENT2,OTHERPAYMENT3,OTHERPAYMENT4,
after that i am running q1 with this result.